# Unexpected Python tuple behaviour

Tags: python

Why am I getting a strange `0   2` result when I give this to Python?

```
#tuples ~wtF?
a=()
b=(a)
c=(a,1)
len(b)
len(c)
```

NB: I get an expected  `1  2` result for lists:

```
a=[]
b=[a]
c=[a,1]
len(b)
len(c)
```

This is happening on Linux:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.2+
```

### Edit: wrt answers so far

So is this somehow because of the `,` in the `c=(a,1)` assignment?

```
>>> print b
()
>>> print c
((), 1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The brackets don't make it a tuple - the comma does. Consider:

```
>>> 5 * (3 + 2)
25
```

The brackets there mean 'do this first'. The brackets in:

```
b=(a)
```

Mean the same. So, this is equivalent to

```
b = a
```

so `b is a` will be `True`.

To make `b` a tuple containing the empty tuple, you need to do:

```
b = a,
```

Again, the brackets don't make it a tuple (except for the special case of `()` is the empty tuple), the comma does.

For the edit,

```
c = (a, 1)
```

Since `a = ()`, this is the same as:

```
c = ((), 1)
```

ie, it is a tuple containing the empty tuple and `1`. `()` is always the empty tuple (same as `[]` is the empty list), but this it the only time the brackets mean 'tuple'. The above is the same as:

```
c = (), 1
```

Though normally people do include the brackets here (and the `repr` and `str` of tuples always do), this is for style rather than because they're meaningful.

Comment: [9000](http://stackoverflow.com/users/223424/9000) beat you to it but i give you a +1 anyhows =)

Answer (score 5):

`(a)` is just an expression `a`, like `(1+2)` is just `1+2`.

If you want 1-item tuple, you write `(a,)`.
BTW same syntax works with lists: `[a,]`. And with function argument lists, too. Trailing comma is acceptable everywhere where a comma-separates list is.